# Do I Still Have to Download Facebook SDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6

I am confused about the Facebook SDK for iOS. iOS includes the Facebook SDK, correct? But on the Facebook Developer site, it still is telling me to download the Facebook SDK and add it to my project... is this necessary? I am able to post from my app to Facebook without doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Social Framework allows your app to login to facebook and post, but only if the user has connected their Facebook account with iOS6 (which not everyone does). The Facebook SDK allows your app to connect to facebook in other ways (including through the Facebook app itself, or through a web view).